# What kind of flooring is this?

Tags: flooring

I'm trying to determine this kind of floor covering, which I saw the other day in a gas station. Any ideas? 
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

that is LVT Luxury vinyl tile. Made for grocery stores by Armstrong. That style looks like the Natural Creations Diamond 10 Technology EarthCuts.

It is extremely durable. It is also quite expensive.

LVT is made by a number of flooring companies. The residential purposed lines are very nice and durable and made on a smaller scale to look right in smaller spaces. Just search for LVT flooring to find tons of options from big name manufacturers. Some are glue down and give the option of grouting with special formula product offered in complimentary colors.

Check out the commercial LVT [here](https://www.armstrongflooring.com/commercial/en-us/products/lvt-luxury-flooring/natural-creations-earthcuts-diamond-10.html)

Answer (score 1):

Probably an "engineered" laminate flooring (like "Pergo") that was made to look like stone. There are a lot more options for that now besides just trying to replicate the look of wood.

Comment: They don't really use engineered laminate for commercial.   Also it looks like there is grout but is hard to tell.   There would have to be closer pictures to tell.